# OCaml - is it operation is efficient?

Tags: ocaml, performance

I wrote code:

```
(h::(List.hd acc))::(List.tl acc)
```

is it efficent this operation ?
What do you think ?

Comment: What is it supposed to do? What is acc?

Comment: tell me if List.tl lst is efficient

Answer (score 3):

If I were asked to improve the efficiency of a function definition `let f h acc = (h :: List.hd acc) :: List.tl acc` without any other background, I would say it is already enough efficient.

Still, I prefer using pattern matching instead of `List.hd` and `List.tl`. It is safer (you naturally find the case `acc = []` must be handled specially), and slightly  faster than the two function calls:

```
let f h = function
  | [] -> invalid_arg "empty list"
  | xs::xss -> (h::xs) :: xss
```